# downgrading sails.js from v0.11.0 to v0.10.5

Tags: node.js, sails.js, downgrade

I have installed sails.js v0.11.0, but I need to downgrade it to v0.10.5 cause a company I'm working for used sails.js v0.10.5 for some codes. Does anyone know how I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
npm uninstall -g sails
npm install -g sails@0.10.5
```

On Unix/MacOS you may need `sudo`

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have sails.js installed localy (e.g. your project folder under node_modules) simply delete the sails folder
2. Go to your package.json and change the sails version to the desired one ( 0.10.5 )
3. run npm install

You should be good to go now